# Issues with booleans in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm pretty new to SSIS, and I'm writing an application to dump a CSV into a table. The table already exists, and it uses the bit field for a boolean. Interestingly in this field, I can manually insert 0,1,true or false. When I query the table, it gives me true or false even if I insert 0 or 1.

Now, when I try to use SSIS to put a true or false, I get an error. If I set the the incoming field to boolean, I get an error right off the bat. If I set the type to string, I get an error at runtime. I've also  tried to convert from string to bool or int to no avail.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 4):

The data flow or expression language makes sense of 1/0 or true/false. However, when it attempts to serialize a boolean to text for the purposes of a flat file, it will save it out as "true" or "false." Don't ask me why, I just know that I explicitly cast those to either a character of 1 or 0 or an integer via a Derived Column. Otherwise, you'll end up with truncation errors.

In my data source, CarOwner is a bit data type. In my Derived Column, I would add a new Column called OwnsCar and use the following expression.

```
CarOwner ? 1 : 0
```

The following Biml describes the package I built. If you have the free download, [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) you can paste that into a new Biml file, fix the values for the Connections below (`localhost\dev2012` and a path of `c:\ssisdata` may not be valid for your environment) and it will emit an SSIS package.

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection 
            ConnectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=tempdb" 
            Name="SRCDB" />
        <FlatFileConnection FilePath="C:\ssisdata\so_31146110" FileFormat="FFF Simple" Name="FF_Boolean" />
    </Connections>
    <FileFormats>
         <FlatFileFormat 
            IsUnicode="false"
            FlatFileType="Delimited"
            Name="FFF Simple">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="CustomerName" DataType="String" Length="20" Delimiter="Tab" />
                <Column Name="OwnsCar" DataType="Int32" Delimiter="Tab" />
                <Column Name="OwnsTruck" DataType="Int32" Delimiter="CRLF" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="BooleanFlatFile">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="QuerySource" DataType="String">
                    <![CDATA[SELECT
    'Customer ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS varchar(2)) AS CustomerName
,   *
FROM
    (
        VALUES
            (CAST(1 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(1 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
    ) S(CarOwner)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        VALUES
            (CAST(1 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
        ,   (CAST(0 AS bit))
    ) F(TruckOwner);
]]></Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT FF_Boolean">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource 
                            ConnectionName="SRCDB" 
                            Name="OLESRC Unpivot Source">
                            <VariableInput VariableName="User.QuerySource" />
                        </OleDbSource>

                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Booleans to ints">
                            <Columns>
                                <Column DataType="Int32" Name="OwnsCar" >CarOwner ? 1 : 0</Column>
                                <Column DataType="Int32" Name="OwnsTruck" >TruckOwner ? 1 : 0</Column>
                            </Columns>
                        </DerivedColumns>

                        <FlatFileDestination ConnectionName="FF_Boolean" Name="FFDST FF_Boolean"></FlatFileDestination>

                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: So, I've made a derived column using this code:
(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(myVar) == "TRUE" ? 1 : 0)
However, the output is all falses, and I checked the data and it contains many trues.

Comment: @billinkc - Hi! I stumbled upon your blog and having a good time going through the same. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
I've imported the field as a string, and then create the variable as a derived column using this formula:
(DT_BOOL)(UPPER(RTRIM(ABC)) == "TRUE" ? 1 : 0)